# Capture screenshot synchronously

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i am writing screen capture in my `Unity3D` program.
with this method:

```
Application.Capturescreenshot("fileName.txt");
```

it works well and it saved to the project root folder.
now i want to move it to another path so i am checking if the file exist line after i am taking the capture, and it turns out that in the next line the capture did not saved yet. it probably happens asynchronous. i want this line to be executed synchronous.

what would be the easiest solution?

Comment: I edited the title of your question to better describe your issue. This will make it easier for future readers to find this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the `CaptureScreenshot` API doesn't give you a way to either do it synchronously or execute a delegate when the file has been saved, then you have two options:

1. Continuously poll to see if the file has been created (flaky, I wouldn't do this), or
2. Use a [`FileSystemWatcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx) to watch the folder for changes. You can give the watcher a delegate that will be executed whenever a file is added to the folder, and you can use the delegate to move the file.